# VS 2008 ADO.NET Entity Data Model questions

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning L2E and have two questions:

1. when I add `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` to my `VS 2008 C#` project. VS will add a cs file for you and the default namespace will be your project name, saying `SystemSoftware` in my case. Can I config VS to create a different namespace, such as `MyCompany.SystemSoftware`, for me or I have to manually change them? If VS can do it for me, please tell me how to setup the VS.
2. how to update the Entity Data Model if my database tables changed? or I have to remove the Model and recreate again?

thanks,

Comment: Those 2 subquestions are totally unrelated. Please ask 1 question per Question.

Answer (score 0):

found answers to my questions:

1. right click the .edmx entry and select the `Properties`. In the Properties window, put your namespace into `Custom Tool Namespace` entry and rebuild, done
2. double click the .edmx entry, the Updata Model Wizard will show up (like a ER diagram), right click on it, select `Update Model from Database ...`, done.